# RedBlackTrees Structure?

Tags: java, red-black-tree

I cannot manage to get my head around redbacktrees, based on this implementation http://pastebin.com/Gg3YbPUg.

```
/**
 * Insert into the tree.
 * @param item the item to insert.
 * @throws DuplicateItemException if item is already present.
 */
public void insert( AnyType item )
{
    current = parent = grand = header;
    nullNode.element = item;

    while( compare( item, current ) != 0 )
    {
        great = grand; grand = parent; parent = current;
        current = compare( item, current ) < 0 ?
                     current.left : current.right;

            // Check if two red children; fix if so
        if( current.left.color == RED && current.right.color == RED )
             handleReorient( item );
    }

        // Insertion fails if already present
    if( current != nullNode )
        throw new DuplicateItemException( item.toString( ) );
    current = new RedBlackNode<AnyType>( item, nullNode, nullNode );

        // Attach to parent
    if( compare( item, parent ) < 0 )
        parent.left = current;
    else
        parent.right = current;
    handleReorient( item );
}
```

I've just made a simple tree using the numbers 1,14,15,2,11,7,5,8

```
// Test program
public static void main( String [ ] args )
{
    RedBlackTree<Integer> t = new RedBlackTree<Integer>( );

    t.insert(1);
    t.insert(14);
    t.insert(15);
    t.insert(2);
    t.insert(11);
    t.insert(7);
    t.insert(5);
    t.insert(8);

    t.printTree();
}
```

And based off the example from http://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/software/AlgAnim/red_black.html, My Tree should look something like...

[image: RBT]

And my console output from the printTree function

```
/**
 * Print all items.
 */
public void printTree( )
{
    printTree( header.right );
}

/**
 * Internal method to print a subtree in sorted order.
 * @param t the node that roots the tree.
 */
private void printTree( RedBlackNode<AnyType> t )
{
    if( t != nullNode )
    {
        printTree( t.left );
        System.out.println("main element is <" + t.element + "("+t.color+")> left <" + t.left.element +"> right <" + t.right.element + ">" );
        printTree( t.right );
    }
}
```

Is...

```
main element is <1(COLOR:RED)> left <8> right <8>
main element is <2(COLOR:BLACK)> left <1> right <5>
main element is <5(COLOR:RED)> left <8> right <8>
main element is <7(COLOR:RED)> left <2> right <14>
main element is <8(COLOR:BLACK)> left <8> right <8>
main element is <11(COLOR:RED)> left <8> right <8>
main element is <14(COLOR:BLACK)> left <11> right <15>
main element is <15(COLOR:RED)> left <8> right <8>
```

(for reading purposes I have renamed 0 and 1 as COLOR RED AND BLACK)
From what I understand the "header" variable is the root of the tree.

If I was to do something like

```
 public void function(AnyType x)
 {
    RedBlackNode<AnyType> n = find(x);
    //what is the parent of n?
 }

/**
 * Find an item in the tree.
 * @param x the item to search for.
 * @return the matching item or null if not found.
 */
public RedBlackNode<AnyType> find( AnyType x )
{
    nullNode.element = x;
    current = header.right;

    for( ; ; )
    {
        if( x.compareTo( current.element ) < 0 )
            current = current.left;
        else if( x.compareTo( current.element ) > 0 ) 
            current = current.right;
        else if( current != nullNode )
            return current;
        else
            return null;
    }
}
```

From the above pastebin implementation of RedBlackTree how do I know what my current parent element is for n?

Comment: If the structure isn't correct, the problem has to be in your `insert(...)` method. Please post it above so we can look at it.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen hey hunter, everything is in the pastebin url provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's a proper red-black tree, abides by the rules, then the root *has* to be black, so 1 cannot be the root.

I've build a red-black tree in Java which has a much better print-out if you are interested:

```
└── (Black) 8
    ├── (Black) 2
    │   ├── (Red) 1
    │   │   ├── (Black) null
    │   │   └── (Black) null
    │   └── (Red) 5
    │       ├── (Black) null
    │       └── (Black) null
    └── (Red) 15
        ├── (Black) 11
        │   ├── (Black) null
        │   └── (Red) 14
        │       ├── (Black) null
        │       └── (Black) null
        └── (Black) 17
            ├── (Black) null
            └── (Black) null
```

[Here](http://code.google.com/p/java-algorithms-implementation/source/browse/src/com/jwetherell/algorithms/data_structures/RedBlackTree.java) is the code to the red-black tree, check out the RedBlackTreePrinter class to see how I built the console output.

Comment: if you could just append this to the end of your current question... I'd greatly appreciate it "From the above pastebin implementation of RedBlackTree how do I know what my current parent element is for n?" (or ill just spend some time and read your code) +1 rep for your answer too.

Comment: @Killrawr I don't know if you noticed but I ran your input "1,14,15,2,11,7,5,8" through my RedBlack tree code to get that output.  The output on the graphic you put up doesn't look right to me, 11->14->15 just doesn't look right.

Comment: @Killrawr It looks like there is no way to get the parent node given n without keeping track of that information on the way down. Essentially, if you search the tree for node "n", keep track of the previous node "p". When you find "n" in the tree, "p" should be it's parent. That's why I explicitly used a parent object in my implementation. Also, looking at the code, header looks to be the root of the tree.

Comment: @Justin Aw okay thats cool thanks! a lot for the fantastic answer anyhow :) and advice